# What is the Green Status icon?

Tags: rune-factory

In the first Rune Factory, under my stats i have this green circle and it hasn't gone away for days, in the menu it's in the bottom right corner.

I am wondering that this icon means and how i got it because i'm sure i didn't start off with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The icon is the Seal Status which blocks spells and charge uses of tools, it can be cured with Roundoff which to my knowledge can only be brought from Edward's Clinic.

I found this out when i went looking to see how to use my upgraded watering can which wasn't working (and the status explains why)